# How does the identity follow?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I can show the simple algebra for the first part, but then having issues showing, how $|z_1||z_2| = |z_1z_2|$ follows from it?

[image]

Comment: Hint : What are the absolute values for $z_1$ and $z_2$ ?

Comment: @Peter Do you mean distance?

Comment: If you want, distance from the origin. A simple rule about square-roots , namely $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is all you need.

Comment: Absolute value, or modulus, can be thought of as the distance the point is from the origin. If $z = x + iy$, then $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|z_1z_2|=|(x_1+y_1i)(x_2+y_2i)|=\sqrt{(x_1x_2-y_1y_2)^2+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2+x_1^2y_2^2+x_2^2y_1^2}=\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2)}=|z_1||z_2|$$

Comment: Why don't you type completely and then post? Why so hurry?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare Because firstly I want to post the hint and during this I understand that I can post the full solution, which I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

$$(|z_1||z_2|)^2=z_1\,\overline{z_1}\,z_2\overline{z_2}=z_1\,z_2\,\overline{z_1}\,\overline{z_2}=(z_1\,z_2)\overline{z_1\,z_2}=|z_1\,z_2|^2$$

Comment: Yes, but how does this follow from previous algebra in the question?